# Preciso validar um layout TXT em C#

Tags: c#, .net, edi

Estou com um arquivo TXT onde eu preciso validar o número de caracteres de cada coluna conforme o layout de cada documento.

Observação: Os documentos estão todos em um único arquivo `*.txt`

Na segunda coluna é o tipo do documento "0000,0400,0430". Cada documento tem um layout diferente que tem que ser verificado.

```
Layout documento 0000
Coluna 1 = 6 caracteres obrigatórios
Coluna 2 = 4 caracteres obrigatórios
Coluna 3 = 8 caracteres obrigatórios
Coluna 4 <= 100 caracteres maximo
Coluna 5 = 1 caracteres obrigatórios
Coluna 6 = 7 caracteres obrigatórios
Coluna 11 = 1 caractere ou vazio

000001|0000|00000000|ABCDFG|U|1234567|201601|201601|2|1||1|123456|1.0|1
000002|0400|123456|1|123456|2|ABCDFG|123456|1234567|1||
000003|0430|123456|1010101111|111000001|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00||0,00|5,00|0,00|||
```

Tenho esse código

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string caminhoArquivo = "C:\\Temp\\Teste.txt";

        try
        {
              var consulta =
              from linha in File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo)
              let clienteDados = linha.Split('|')
              where clienteDados[1] == "0000"
              select new Cliente()
              {
                  Num_Linha = clienteDados[0],
                  Reg = clienteDados[1],
                  CNPJ = clienteDados[2],
                  Nome = clienteDados[3],
              };

            foreach (var item in consulta)
            {               
                Console.WriteLine(item.Num_Linha + "|" + item.Reg + "|" + item.CNPJ + "|" + item.Nome + "|");
                Console.WriteLine(item.Num_Linha.Length == 6);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Reg.Length == 4);
                Console.WriteLine(item.CNPJ.Length == 8);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Nome.Length <= 100);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Reg);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" Erro : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Cliente.class

```
public class Cliente
  {       
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Num_Linha { get; set; }
    public string Reg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Você quer apenas validar ou utilizar o arquivo?

Comment: Apenas fazer a validação.

Comment: @Britto, Esse arquivo parece ser do SPED, estou certo? Caso sim tenho um código que pode te ajudar.

Comment: É sim @Robss70 estou precisando de um help nisso

Comment: Você precisa validar todos os registros ou só alguns? Por que caso for validar todos antes de importar você terá que ter uma classe com todos os tipos de registros e isso é um trabalho absurdo. Antes de importar o arquivo geralmente só se valida o registro |0000| e o contador total de linhas registro |9999|.  Após importado você trata somente os registro que lhe interessa. Mas vou postar um exemplo e veja se lhe ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

O caminho é usar [o pacote NuGet FileHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/). Ele é uma ferramenta que lida com esses tipos de arquivos, ainda que as linhas sejam diferentes.

Como as linhas são diferentes de acordo com a 2a coluna, [é um caso de multiregistros](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/) e a solução pode dar um pouquinho de trabalho.

Minha sugestão é você criar uma classe para cada tipo de documento:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Registro0000
{
    public string NumeroLinha;
    public string TipoDocumento;
    public string Campo1;
    public string Campo2;
    public string Campo3;
    ...
}

[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Registro0400
{
    public string NumeroLinha;
    public string TipoDocumento;
    public string Campo1;
    public string Campo2;
    public string Campo3;
    ...
}

// Escreva os demais seguindo mais ou menos este padrão.
```

Na hora de ler este arquivo, você precisará instanciar um:

```
var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof (Registro0000),
    typeof (Registro0400),
    typeof (Registro0430), /* Coloque aqui as demais classes */);

engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(CustomSelector);

var resultado = engine.ReadFile("SeuArquivo.txt");

foreach (var registro in resultado)
    Console.WriteLine(registro.ToString());
```

Por fim, escreva o selecionador de registros:

```
private Type CustomSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
{
    if (recordLine.Length == 0)
        return null;

    switch (recordLine.Substring(7, 10)) 
    {
        case "0000":
            return typeof (Registro0000);
        case "0400":
            return typeof (Registro0400);
        case "0430":
            return typeof (Registro0430);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Eu já tinha visto essa ferramenta, para o que estou fazendo não serve muito bem, Mas muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Por que não? Você pega `resultado` da ferramenta e aplica uma lógica sua de validação.

Comment: Eu já tenho pronto o que o FileHelpers faz.

Comment: Então atualize sua pergunta com o que você tem pronto, por favor.

Comment: Sem ter uma amostra do código é impossível apontar uma resposta.

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta, por favor. Não comente a resposta com código.

Answer (score 2):

@Britto, numa situação análoga, eu usei awk/gawk, com bastante versatilidade. Eu sei que a solução que aponto não cumpre 
as condições que referes, ainda assim penso que poderá ser útil.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{ FS="[|]"}

 $2 == "0000"  &&   v0000() { print "ok"; next }
 $2 == "0400"  &&   v0400() { print "ok"; next }
 $2 == "0430"  &&   v0430() { print "ok"; next }
                              { print NR ": invalid " $2 " record"; next }

function v0000(){               ## valida registos 0000
  return( length($1)==6   &&
          length($2)==4   &&
          length($4)<=100 &&
          length($11)<=1 )
}

function v0400(){               ## sem restrições
  return 1
}

function v0430(){
  return( length($1)==6   &&
          length($2)==4   &&
          $4 ~ /^[01]+$/ )      ## $4 contem apenas seq de "0" e "1"
}
```

(gawk é uma ferramenta minúscula que corre em qualquer sistema operativo)

- NR - número do registo (número da linha)
- FS - field separator

Answer (score 2):

@Britto existem muitas maneiras de validar o arquivo txt que voce menciona, esta aqui é uma delas, é feia mais está funcionado, eu exclui algumas partes para reduzir o tamanho.

O método lê o arquivo até o fim, então você pode colocar quantos registro quiser, por exemplo `if (xxxxxxxx.StartsWith("|xxxx|"))` e ir fazendo as validações que precisa.

Nesta parte `_reg0000 = reg0000.Split(delimitador, StringSplitOptions.None);` 
ele vai jogar no array  `string[] _reg0000;` e de acordo com o tamanho você compara com a quantidade de colunas que o |0000| deve ter.

```
public void valida(string path_txt)
    {
        StringReader streamReader = new StringReader(path_txt);

        string reg0000;

        string[] _reg0000;

        char[] delimitador = new char[] { '|' };

        while ((reg0000 = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (reg0000.StartsWith("|0000|"))
            {
                try
                {
                    _reg0000 = reg0000.Split(delimitador, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    // 
                    //faça aqui as validações que achar preciso, por exemplo a quantidade de colunas.
                    //
                    //
                    //
                    //

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```